# react-currency-format is not installing, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use react-currency-format library in my project, but I cannot install the package.
I think there is something wrong with dependencies but I couldnt figure out what is conflicting with what.

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-02-20T09:51:09.030Z

While resolving: x-clone@0.1.0
Found: react@17.0.1
node_modules/react
  react@"^17.0.1" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.0.0
node_modules/react-currency-format
  react-currency-format@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "17.0.1",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "x-clone",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "path": "/Users/Hamed_Iam/Desktop/x-clone"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "^17.0.1",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/Hamed_Iam/Desktop/x-clone"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "react-currency-format",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "x-clone",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "path": "/Users/Hamed_Iam/Desktop/x-clone"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/react-currency-format",
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "react-currency-format",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/Hamed_Iam/Desktop/x-clone"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "peerConflict": null,
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

I also tried `npm install react-currency-format --save` but it didnt work.
my npm version is 7.5.3 and node v14.15.4, I dont want to use `--force`. is there a fix for it?

Comment: Please get familiar with it. `create a Minimal, Reproducible Example` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dipenparmar12 sure, when I come across a problem that is reproducible, I'll keep that in mind, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

use --force like this:  npm install react-currency-format --save --force

Answer (score 2):

Currently React has come up with an Update so its better to use **--force** and **--save** together.

```
npm install react-currency-format --save --force
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided above accept potentially breaking dependencies in certain packages when using the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` params which can cause issues between build environments if they are not configured correctly.

Nobody really explained ***why*** this error was being thrown and how to fix it without using the `--force` param - as mentioned in the title lol.
I ran into this exact same problem in a React project when upgrading to `18.2.0` and wasn't happy with using the `--force` param either so here's my attempt at explaining why and how to *'fix'* it:

### It's useful to know this first:

Given a version number **MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH**, increment the:

1. **PATCH**: Bug fixes and other minor changes: Patch release, increment the last number, e.g. 0.0.1
2. **MINOR**: New features which don’t break existing features: Minor release, increment the middle number, e.g. 0.1.0
3. **MAJOR**: Changes which break backwards compatibility: Major release, increment the first number, e.g. 1.0.0

### ***Why*** this is happening:

1. You are installing React `17.0.1`.
2. The `react-currency-format` package being installed is `1.0.0` and inside it's `package.json` there is an object called `peerDependencies` that lists versions of ***other*** packages that the ***current*** package requires to run.
3. The `peerDependencies` in `1.0.0` of `react-currency-format` do not contain `^17.0.0` so NPM V7 and later throws an error as this dependency is not listed

The object I'm referring to in the `package.json` file looks like this:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0"
},
```

### How to fix this:

Create a fork of the repo and update the `peerDependencies` object to include `^17.0.0` like so:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0"
},
```

This is by no means a blanket fix for all packages as they may in some cases need to be updated for major version releases but this fixes the issue for now without having to use `--force`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use it like this: npm install react-currency-format --save --force

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to install it :

```
npm install react-currency-format --save --force
```